# EEA Family Permit refused - No clear reason given, appalling letter

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, marriage, family

Please can anyone advise how to deal with this?

We applied for an EEA Family Permit for my wife to travel from Russia to join me in the UK. We enclosed our passports, my Permanent Residence certificate, and our marriage certificate (with certified translation from Russian to English).

It is not even clear on what grounds the permit was refused, and the letter is appallingly worded. How to deal with this kind of incompetence?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That notice certainly seems sloppy, contradictory, and incomplete. How did you submit your application? Was it done through an agency of some kind?

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: Submitted ourselves -- filled the form online, made sure if was filled thoroughly and carefully, then printed out and took to the branch at the specified address in St. Petersburg along with the required supporting documents.

Comment: This document was obviously corrupted. I wonder if you were even refused, or if this mess is simply what got sent out.

Answer (score 6):

The letter is a template that was not completed correctly (perhaps not at all).  For example, certain text should have been deleted by the Entry Clearance Officer (ECO) and replaced with more informative text.  These phrases include "enter sponsor's name" and "enter the relevant regulation number(s) (see ECGs EUN2.23)."

Also note the self-contradictory nature of the letter: one paragraph explains that you may not appeal the decision, while the following section describes your right of appeal.  Similarly, the letter notes that "it has not been necessary to interview you" immediately before claiming that "an interview with you" was considered in making the decision.

Most egregiously, the portion of the letter that should outline the ECO's reasoning is entirely absent.  This should appear between the heading "The Decision" and the concluding paragraph beginning "I therefore refuse...."  In this spot, however, there is only a single bullet with no associated text.

You should approach the Entry Clearance Manager (ECM) at the relevant consulate and request a properly completed notice.

See also [UK visa blank refusal letter without reason for refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93879/19400) at [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Sadly there seems to be no recourse. The applications in St. Petersburg are outsourced to a private company TLScontact - this is where they take in your application, then forward to UKVI, and then return the decision letter to you. There are no ECOs or ECMs there. The British Consulate also could not do anything other than advise contacting Home Office at the general switchboard number. HO only offer general advice over the phone, and advised to send a written complaint to the main office in Liverpool.

Comment: @Mihael then write to the main office in Liverpool.  Also reapply.  Then you don't have to wonder which would be faster; you'll find out.